# Register background task, Dictionary.First() method issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I'm working on a small app for Windows 8 in C# with Visual Studio 2012. I'm trying to register a task in background thanks to this tutorial :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709906.aspx

However, this line gives me an error (the word "first" is underlined) :

```
var iter = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks
    .first();
```

This is the error :

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'first' and no extension method 'first' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) MainPage.xaml.cs

So I checked if all the libraries were here. Looks like yes, among them :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

I googled my error and looked for stuff about IReadOnlyDictionary but didn't find anything, and since I'm a beginner in Windows dev... I ask for your help :)

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want `First()`, what you used is `first()`.

I recommend `FirstOrDefault()` if you did not check if there is a task. Else you will get an exception.

If you still don't get the First() method, check your imports for:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thanks ! (and for the other answers too.)

So the source of the problem was a mistake on Microsoft's tutorial...

Comment: For people getting problems with the next part of MSDN's tutorial, check this :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/fc67c5d0-1439-4bd7-915f-df9c5e67b68f/pas-de-dfinitions-hascurrent-movenext?forum=winstoreappsfr

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive! `First` has an upper case `F`

```
var iter = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks
    .First();
```

The relevant namespace is `System.Linq` which imports the [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) `First`. It's not a member of the tasks collection but a member of the static class `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

You must import this namespace in order to use the extension method

```
using System.Linq;
```

The Extension methods in this namespace extend `IEnumerable<T>` which is implemented by the task collection in your case.

Extension methods look like being members of the type they extend, but in fact this is only compiler magic. The compiler transforms the code to the following, internally:

```
var iter = Enumerable.First(
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks);
```

And you could call it like this as well.

Answer (score 0):

`First()` not `first()`.  C# is a case sensitive language. replace with

```
var iter = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks
.First();
```

But I would also take BlueM's adive if you aren't validating that the task is present some place else within your code.

The reason you weren't able to find more about your issue is because the error thrown is just stating the method you called can't be found.  I had the same issue happen to me the other day with and extra semi-colon.  I searched around on the internet for about an hour before I looked back at my code and realized what I had done.

Though these error codes may be confusing, if you look at the end of the message,

`(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

We know `First()` is a method we can call, it's predefined.  Logically we know that it must have been our error as the developer if we are calling a method that doesn't even take parameters and is predefined but still throwing the error.  I hope this helps, not sure if you are new to programming or just c#.